# How to display print_r result in source code with multiple lines

Tags: php

I have a simple php code which changes the order of the name inside an array.

```
$arr = [
    "Meier, Peter",
    "Schulze, Monika",
    "Schmidt, Ursula",
    "Brosowski, Klaus",
];

foreach($arr as $name => $name2) 
{
    $vname = explode(", ", $name2); 
    $new = array_reverse($vname);
    $arr[$name] = implode(", ", $new); 
}

echo "<pre>".print_r($arr, true)."</pre>";
```

Basically I would like the edit the code, that the source code displays the array not in one line, but in several lines (one for each Firstname + Lastname) like shown below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Peter, Meier
    [1] => Monika, Schulze
    [2] => Ursula, Schmidt
    [3] => Klaus, Brosowski
)
```

Right now the source code shows the excelpt same result, but only in one line. Is it possible to adapt the print_r command in this way?

Best Regards

Edit for clarification:
my code gives as a result the array which I have also posted in my question. In the html source code, the same array is in one line[0] => Peter, Meier [1] => Monika, Schulze and so on. So there is a difference between the way my result is structured and how the source code is structured. I would like to change the source code structure of the array, that it looks like the actual result.

Comment: What do you mean by "only in one line"? Your code shows exactly what you expect it to show : https://3v4l.org/LLvZW

Comment: @tcj He means "the first name and the last name on the same line"

Comment: I really do not understand the question. If you can rephrase or reply to my comment, it will help

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it makes more sense now. Maybe I have reached my limit to explain the problem in english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adopt the line_breaks from print_r for html with the function nl2br()

```
echo nl2br(print_r($arr, true));
```

or you build a List function with

```
echo '<ul>'.PHP_EOL;
foreach($arr as $name){
    echo "<li>{$name}</li>".PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found out what you were trying to say:

output is based on https://3v4l.org/LLvZW from @tcj

- When printing with print_r your output looks like this:
  [image: List item]
- When you inspect your HTML elements in your browser your inspector shows this:

  (Note: everything is in one line)
  [image]

The clarifications:

the output looks like this because `<pre>` does set a fixed width, and `white-space: pre;` 
If you remove `white-space: pre;` you should end with an output like this:

[image]

If you inspect your element in the browser, it will still all be in one line

**HOWEVER, if you try to edit the element inside your browser inspector then it WON'T be in one line.**

[image: <code>white-space: pre;</code>]

So my answer to this is, that I assume this is some **optimization done by the browser**.
Probably so you can see more of the other HTML you have, or for other reasons... 
 (Im on Firefox btw.)